# Facebook OAuth redirect problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth

A bit of reference from [facebook developer page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#authenticating-users-in-a-web-application)

Here is my question.. All the redirections are done followed the instructions above to the letter the fb server returns a acsess token in a plain unformatted string. Which would be fine if i was doing a desktop app or iPhone but, it's a browser centric app. any ides why https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token doesn't redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when this is by design, which is not clever on Facebook's part, anyways instead of redirecting again you could use `WebClient` to do the request your self to get the oauth token, if anyone else is wondering.

Answer (score 2):

why, https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token does give a redirect in a web application,
just mention your url in redirect_uri =

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
client_id=...&
redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/oauth_redirect
```

If this is not what you asked , please be little specific in your question

Comment: are you sure your url is valid and you have that same url domain registered for getting APPID and APPSecret

Answer (score 1):

yes oauth always send redirection to your mentioned url http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#authenticating-users-in-a-web-application